# c# SDK initialize one interface with multiple objects

Tags: c#, wpf

I am currently development an app based on `c#` SDK COM library and can anyone advise how to program with multiple objects based on one library because I have more than one device to control :

what I am doing now :

```
private libraryOpenInterface _libraryOI1;
private libraryOpenInterface _libraryOI2;
private libraryOpenInterface _libraryOI3;
private libraryOpenInterface _libraryOI4;
```

and I need to link-up with each interface with a different login account and I have more than 20 devices which I think there is better way to implement this:

```
_libraryOI1.connect ( 192.168.1.1, admin,admin);
_libraryOI2.connect ( 192.168.1.2, admin,admin);
_libraryOI3.connect ( 192.168.1.3, admin,admin);
_libraryOI4.connect ( 192.168.1.4, admin,admin);
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using separate variables rather than a collection (e.g. a `List<T>` or an array)?

Comment: because i need separate variable and each variable is referring to one device , and i have 20 devices with different login account and other function parameters

Comment: *Why* do you believe you need those separate variables though? Instead of 20 separate variables, you could use a single `List<LibraryOpenInterface>` with 20 elements. What do you believe you wouldn't be able to accomplish that way?

Comment: I don't understand why _libraryOI1, _libraryOI2 and so on use the same interface... looks like they are all the same service. or maybe you mean different interfaces?

Comment: hi thanks for your advice and i tried : List<PraesideoOpenInterface_V0430> IO = new List<PraesideoOpenInterface_V0430>; error shows : the type or namespace 'list' could not be found .

Comment: Well that's probably because you're missing a `using` directive for `System.Collections.Generic`. It doesn't mean there's anything wrong with the approach I'm suggesting - I'd just assumed you already knew about generic collections. If you don't, I would recommend taking a step back and learning more about some of the core library features used in .NET before going into specialist areas like COM integration. You're likely to save a *lot* of time that way.

Comment: yes its referring to the same interface , but i need to declare different variables in order to pass in different parameters  like device 1 : _libraryOI1.call ( Zone1 , Msg , StartChime );    device 2 :_libraryOI2.call ( Zone16 , Msg , StartChime );

Comment: Sure , thanks Mr. Daisy Shipton

Comment: No, you don't need multiple variables. You need multiple *objects*. A collection allows you to store multiple elements in a single collection. I suggest you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/collections

Comment: ok thanks . i will study the documents above and come back to this post before i fully understand . thanks a lot Mr Daisy Shipton

Comment: @DaisyShipton hi sir , i have created a class called NCO and consume my SDK inside the class private static List<NCO> POIList = new List<NCO>(); ,  and i dont get what you mean by multiple objects .  what should i store into the collection list ? connection variable ? number of devices interfaces

Comment: @LohZhiCheng: I'm not sure what your `NCO` class is meant to be - but in your sample code you have multiple `libraryOpenInterface` variables, so I'd expected it to be a `List<libraryOpenInterface>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to store you login information: IP, user,passowrd in some configuration.. either `app.config`, or better looks like a `database` or whatever.. make sure you encrypt the passowrd.

Secondlly the code should look like :

```
private libraryOpenInterface m_LibraryOI1;

private IEnumrable<DeviceCredentialsModel>  getDevicesCredentials()
{
    #get from db of configuration
}

void connectToAllDevices()
{
    var devices = getDevicesCredentials();
    foreach(device in devices)
    {
        var encryptedPassword = device.password;
        var decryptedPassword = ...decrypt;
        m_LibraryOI1.connect(device.ip, v.user, decryptedPassword);
    }
}
```

I still dont understand why you have multiple intances of the same Interface! please explain that part

If you really really want a seperate `Connector Service` for each `machine` so you need to use some kind of factory as well:

```
private Dictionary<DeviceConnectionTypeEnum, IConnector> m_DeviceConnectorToType ..... <-you need to populate this dicionary

private IEnumrable<DeviceCredentialsModel>  getDevicesCredentials()
{
    #get from db of configuration
}

void connectToAllDevices()
{
    var devices = getDevicesCredentials();
    foreach(device in devices)
    {
        var encryptedPassword = device.password;
        var decryptedPassword = ...decrypt;
        var deviceConnectionTypeEnum = device.DeviceConnectionTypeEnum;
        IConnector deviceConnector = m_DeviceConnectorToType[deviceConnectionTypeEnum];

        deviceConnector.connect(device.ip, v.user, decryptedPassword);
    }
}
```

Comment: That way the OP ends up with a single `libraryOpenInterface` object, which I suspect isn't what they want. I think they should be using a collection. As a side-note, I'd also recommend following .NET naming conventions for all methods when giving sample code. I realize the OP's code already violates that, but answers don't have to :)

Comment: @Daisy Shipton Yea, I made it a bit quick and dirty. I think he needto use one instance, he is just confusing. any how he must map between the instance and the credentails some how. So for that situation he must use an `Enum` like `eConnectorServiceType` and then add a `dictionary` to map the enum to the appropriate `Service`

Comment: I see no reason why an enum would necessarily be needed, but the OP really *does* seem to be under the impression that they need multiple instances, and I don't see anything in the comments that implies they're incorrect about that belief.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton see my update for multiple instances using a dictionally as a mapping factory

Comment: Again, I see no indication of a need for an enum. This answer feels like it's trying to go into way more complexity than is required - I suspect that all that's really needed is a list. As for "I still dont understand why you have multiple intances of the same Interface" - we don't know what this library does, but suppose it's connecting to multiple IoT devices, and the app wants to monitor the status of each device. It would make perfect sense to have an instance per device.

Comment: @Daisy Shipton if he has multiple instances so a mapper is a must, if he wants to do it dynamically my solution is the only way I know of. If not dynamically so he needs to do it hard coded

Comment: "so a mapper is a must" - I don't understand why you believe that; why you're completely confident that a list wouldn't be enough. It's possible that mapping would be required, but we don't currently have enough information to say that IMO. However, this discussion probably isn't beneficial any more, so I won't add anything further.